Is there a way to increase the timeout value for WiFi authentication in windows machines?
For context, I've setup a Windows (Win server 2022) NPS server with the Azure MFA extension to enable authentication via RADIUS, using Microsoft credentials, on a wireless network. The RADIUS client is a Unifi U6 PRO access point and PEAP-MSCHAPv2 is used.
Absolutely every device I tested with, apart from Windows machines (both 10 and 11), worked as expected: user enters username and password > MFA push notification pops out > user accepts > authentication is completed both on the device and on the RADIUS server. I tested this with Linux machines, iOS phones and Androids.
For windows however, after the MFA request is approved, before the ChallengeResponse request reaches the server, hence before validating the authenticity, the username-password prompt reappears on the machine's screen, and even though the server does send a AccessAccept request, the laptop is not connected to the network and the NPS logs show this error:
Authentication failed due to an EAP session timeout; the EAP session with the access client was incomplete. I did try to change the Framed-MTU, constraint as some online-found solutions suggested, but it didn't help.
I found this article on Unifi, that presents a similar issue with authentication timeouts. However that is on the AP's side, and in my case it behaves normally with non-windows devices.
This is what gave me the idea of fiddling with the timeout value directly at the source of the issue, but i can't seem to be able to find a way to do this.
I've exhausted every other resource available on this topic, so every bit of insight helps.

2 comments because 2 links. Not sure if it helps (I do not use RADIUS), just found some info in google. The first one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/310266/nps-radius-clients-not-authenticating

The second one: https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/authentication-failed-due-to-an-eap-session-timeout-the-eap-session-with-the-access-client-was-incomplete/170627144617977
